# Stream decoding base64 and quoted-printable in PHP

Tags: php, base64, decode, quoted-printable

As i have discovered

```
stream_filter_append($cin, 'convert.quoted-printable-decode');
```

and

```
stream_filter_append($cin, 'convert.base64-decode');
```

don't decode stream line-by-line. These functions both first read the whole stream until EOF and then decode its data as string.

Is there any soution to decode base64 and quoted-printable encoded streams line-by-line?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was a mistake. These filters **do** convert streams sequentially, block by block.